# Code to extract a value from html code in Python

Tags: python, html

I need an urgent help for the issue described below.I am automating a
project using selenium python bindings

Scenario : creating a new member with a profile picture and add this
member to a group.Then check whether the profile picture given to the
member at the time of profile creation is the same when it appears in
the friends list

For this I would like to compare the image Ids at the time of profile
creation and in the friends list?

I have found out the image id using firebug.Image Id is given inside a

```
<div><a class=........Imageid=234563453.....................>
```

But how can I extract this Image Id from the ?

```
print self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("")._getattribute_(ImageId)
```

Can anybody provide me the code to extract this Imageid from `<a class>` ???

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex.

```
s = "<a class=........Imageid=234563453.....................>"
m = re.search("Imageid=\d*",s)
print m.group().split('=')[1]
```

Comment: Hi pylover, Thanks for the reply.However i want to tell you that,here you have manually taken the <a class...> tag and assigned to variable "S" This is not the proper way because if we take the value manually then we can use 'Contains(value)' to compare Image ids of two picture.Instead I want to extract the value from the Image id in the run time itself.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i do not understand what you want, but if ImegeId is attribute, only way is to using xpath to, if not , search over element's html by regex.